# OAuth 2 approach and refresh token security for SPA and Native Apps

Tags: mobile, oauth, single-page-application, auth0, okta

What is an appropriate secure way to use OAuth 2.0 with SPA applications and Native Apps?

I have seen conflicting opinions in stack overflow and vendor documentation on whether OAuth refresh tokens should be stored in the browser for SPA's and in Native Mobile Apps.

For example here I have 3 links, one of them IETF including receiving refresh token in the App.  While several others including auth0 recommend against receiving refresh token on the client side.

https://www.pingidentity.com/en/company/blog/posts/2018/oauth-recommendations-for-single-page-apps.html

https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp212

https://community.auth0.com/t/obtaining-refresh-token-along-with-access-token-in-a-spa/6476

https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/oidc

Comment: My view is to have the initial token only at session storage and make sure to have the expiration time less. It is always good to get new refresh token from authorization server and override the session with updated token.

Answer (score 1):

They are different answers.

For SPA, the Authorization Code flow without sending client secret is used ( check Arron Parecki's blog posts on the subject ). As a fallback, the implicit flow is less secure but can also be used if you understand the risks.

For mobile native, the best practice is Authorization Code flow with PKCE ( pixie ) 
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/12/13/oauth-2-for-native-and-mobile-apps